# "Object does not match target type" when calling methods using string in C#

Tags: c#, string, methods, reflection, invoke

I'm trying to call a method using a string, but there a problem:

```
void make_moviment(string mov,Vector3 new_mov){
    GameObject past_panel = GameObject.Find(actual_level.ToString());
    Type t = Type.GetType(past_panel.GetComponents<MonoBehaviour>()[0].GetType ().Name);
    MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("get_answer");
    method.Invoke(t,new object[] { mov }));   <--- PROBLEM HERE
}
```

There's always this error "Object does not match target type" related with the last line. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: please show the signature for `get_answer`.

Comment: You're trying to invoke the `get_answer` method on an object of type `Type` (i.e. the variable `t`). Hard to tell what you are trying to do, but it looks like you want to execut it against `past_panel.GetComponents<MonoBehaviour>()[0]` instead.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG it worked!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
method.Invoke(t,new object[] { mov }));
```

Is the same as calling

```
t.WhateverTheMethodIs(mov);
```

But `t` is the `Type`, not the object of that type. You need to pass in the object to call the method on there instead. (Or null if the method is static).

Comment: Thanks man! Just changed from "t" to  "past_panel.GetComponents<MonoBehaviour>()[0]" and it worked!

Comment: Cool. If this answer solved your problem you can click the tick to the top left to mark it as having done so.